# Positioning in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

While creating a site I've noticed that IE places things slightly differently from Chrome or Firefox.

I mean I have one thing below another and in Firefox and chrome there is a 15px space between them. But in Ie its more like 25px. I keep reading about designing for all browsers. But how do I do that because If I make it look right in one browser it will always be different in another.

Do I move it to suit IE? Because then it will look wrong in Chrome.

Comment: There isn't really a question here to answer. If you want it to work in IE, you will keep configuring your code to work in IE. If there is a specific circumstance that you can't fix for IE, post it on Stack Overflow with a copy of the code and we can help you out.

Comment: Use something like normalize.css or reset.css (google those) to get browsers to behave similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep tweaking your code untill it looks good for all browsers

Another option would be to have a seperate style sheet for IE. this would allow you to design for IE as well but you would need to keep in mind that you have 2 style sheets and would need to work on both when you make changes to your site

Answer (score 1):

First of all welcome to web development!

What you can do is load a "Conditional stylesheet" which will only load in IE,

Chris Coyier from CSS-Tricks does a great job of explaining this so take a look here
http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

That should help you out, but it is a tricky task getting everything cross browser compliant but not impossible, just keep at it and you'll get there.

Good luck man!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a css reset first in your style sheet. The reset will customize all the attributes which you can define as per your needs. The main purpose of the css reset is acheiving complete control of all the attributes and defining a generic behaviour for the browsers. Tweaks will help, but in long run, a balanced solution has to be implemented for major things to work out well.

Below are some popular CSS Resets that you can use.

1. [Eric Mayer Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)
2. [Yahoo Reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/)

Hope this helps.